# nanosleep not working with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, sleep, usleep

I have a problem with the nanosleep() function.

In a test project, it works as expected.
In the real project, it does not: it is like if the sleeping time was zero.

As far as I can see, the biggest difference between the test and the real project is the number of threads: one in the test, two in the real one.

Could this be the reason?

If I put the nanosleep call in the code run by one thread, shouldn't that thread pause?

Thank you.

Comment: We have absolutely no idea what you are doing. I shouldn't be hard to write some small piece of code that people here can compile and see for themselves the behaviour that you are experiencing with it...

Comment: `nanosleep` should work in a thread. By the way, does it return 0? If not, what's the `errno` value? It can be interrupted by a signal (giving `errno == EINTR`)

Comment: Have you considered that it might be a release/debug mode build?

Comment: Take current time before sleep and current time after sleep, and compare times. This will tell you if sleep is working or not.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: Yes, nanosleep returns 0.

Comment: Don't you return from `main` in the *real* project too early? (It's exiting the *whole* program, just like a call to `exit`)

Comment: @PlasmaHH: this was a general question about the nanosleep() function in a multithreaded environment. I did not add the code on purpose because it would not have added any useful information.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep - no reason why it wouldn't work in multithreaded app.  the problem is probably somewhere else.  *In the real project, it does not: it is like if the sleeping time was zero.*  how do you know?  this looks like an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3):

This happened with me too and the problem was that i was setting the `timespec.tv_nsec` property with a value beyond `999999999`. When you do that, the value "leaks" to the `tv_sec` property and stops working properly. Yet, the function don't give you any warnings or errors. Please make sure the value of the `tv_nsec` property is below the maximum of `999999999`.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux 3.7 rc5+, it certainly works:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


double time_to_double(struct timeval *t)
{
    return t->tv_sec + (t->tv_usec/1000000.0);
}

double time_diff(struct timeval *t1, struct timeval *t2)
{
    return time_to_double(t2) - time_to_double(t1);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "No argument(s) given...\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
    long x = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 0);

    struct timeval t1, t2;

    struct timespec tt, rem;

    tt.tv_sec = x / 10000000000;
    tt.tv_nsec = x % 10000000000;

    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

    nanosleep(&tt, &rem);


    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

    printf("Time = %16.11f s\n", time_diff(&t1, &t2));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

run like this: `/a.out 10000 200000 100000000 20000000000`

Gives:

```
Time =    0.00007009506 s
Time =    0.00026011467 s
Time =    0.10008978844 s
Time =    2.00009107590 s
```

Comment: not sure what the point of this is?  to test whether there is a bug in nanosleep?  your test app is not even multithreaded?  is there something I am missing?